# Emgu Image<Bgr,byte> Parameter not valid

Tags: c#, emgucv

Here is the problem I met. I had created a class for processing images and return the text inside.

But when I start using `Image<Bgr, byte>`, it returns

> Parameter is not valid.

The other classes are no problem on this except cropping and OCR find text. I can't figure out why the same code processing the same image might cause this. Anyone can help? Please?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4OOHUCv2tcw

Comment: what's the version of EmguCV? Try to check the source code using a decompiler like ILSpy, find the constructor of this class `Image<Bgr, byte>`, and find out what it is checking against before throwing this ArgumentException.

Comment: I will try both, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK, here I had figured out what is the problem. If the file loaded is not in .bmp format (Bitmap) and just use it directly into EmguCV (such as just reading a .jpg or .png file into System.Drawing.Image and convert it into Bitmap), it will shows parameter invalid because of invalid format of image. Or maybe is my image source from a random Snipping Tool screenshot causing this problem.